# Page not found rendering instead of views file in express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to render the static pages in my public folder but when I try and render the pagenotfound middleware comes up and when I remove the middleware, I keep getting the following error

```
Cannot GET /
```

this is my code in my app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const signup = require('./routers/sign-up')

const pagenotfound = require('./middleware/pagenotfound')


// middleware
app.use(express.static('./public'))
app.use(express.json())

app.use('/api/v1/', signup)

app.use(pagenotfound)


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

const start = async () => {
    try {
        app.listen(port, console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

start()
```

the structure of the public folder is

```
    Index.html
    css folder
    javascript frontend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `static` middleware looks for files relative to the folder where the `node` process runs, so your code works only if that contains the `public` folder. Specify the full path to the public folder, for example,

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

if the `public` folder is in the same directory as `app.js`.

Comment: still not working, what is happening is that the pagenotfound middleware is rendered. Instead I want to render the index,html

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: So funny thing, on my windows machine, the code is running smoothly but on my linux machine im'having problems; otherwise thank you for your answer