# how to include static files (html ,css) in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, static

i am not able to include static CSS file in the express app

I have used app.use(express.static('public') still in the output file CSS in not include

```js
// initialize modules       //  ATHARVA BHAVSAR
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");

//creating app from express method
const app = express();

//body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//including static files in the app
app.use(express.static("public"));

//get method for the app
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

//post method for the app
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  //getting the entries from the user
  const FirstName = req.body.Fname;
  const LastName = req.body.Lname;
  const Email = req.body.email;

  //trial
  console.log(FirstName, LastName, Email);
});

//listening to port 3000
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69689144/16462950

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're including the static files correctly, but how are your folder structure looking like? since you called `app.use(express.static("public"));` your css should be inside a folder called "public", also can I take a look at your html? You still need to link your css in your html file, you know right?